# Weird 8-character hash

Tags: hash, password-cracking

I'm investigating an application. In a XML file I came across:

```
<ScrambledPassword>U8P3J2N1</ScrambledPassword>
```

I ran it through a hash identification script which is telling me it's a CRC-32 or FCS-32 both of which seem unlikely to me.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Why do you think this is unlikely?

Comment: @Purefan, CRC-32 and FCS-32 are both 32-bit checksums, which would be expressed in ASCII as eight hexadecimal digits.  "U", "P", "J", and "N" are not hex digits.

Comment: What application are you investigating?

Answer (score 4):

My first instinct is that it's some homebrew algorithm. It might be online somewhere, but there are a million of these homebrew algorithms. It's unlikely you could find it if it's something obscure, though you can try a few top google hits just to see.

Another idea is that it's encrypted and stored with some weird encoding (since I see letters but it's not base64). Or it might use some custom encryption.

It could be a fun challenge to crack this system but we'd probably need to be able to create our own hashes. For example if you have two users with the same password, do they have the same scrambled password? Does the algorithm do something funny when you pass it all zero bytes (0x00)? Etc.

I'm not sure what you need this for, but I'd look at ways around it. If you bought a website and it uses this, just replace the hashing algorithm with bcrypt or something. Or if you're looking at software to potentially buy, you can tell the vendor you're interested in the security of their product and ask details about the hashing algorithm. If they refuse to give it, that's a big red flag. Nobody who understands security evades or denies questions regarding their use of algorithms.

Answer (score 4):

Doesn't look like a hash to me, and its labeled "scrambled". That would lead me to think this is a simple substitution cipher. Do you control this value? i.e. can you try entering in a longer password to see what the result is? When I've come across this in the past and I've controlled the value, I've entered the same letter multiple times, i.e "aaaaaaaa", to see what the output is. Then, try "bbbbbbbb" to see if a pattern emerges ;)